# Error while downgrading mongodb to 1.8 from 2.6

Tags: mongodb

ugraded mongodb to version 2.6 from 1.8. Now I want to downgrade to 1.8 from 2.6- To do this, i deleted 2.6 completely and installed 1.8 freshly. After installing 1.8, when i try to load data getting error---
 Assertion failure:_unindex failed collectionname.$*id*
Assertion failure:_unindex:invalid bsonobj size

Not able to load data.

Comment: They probably updated the on-disk format and you cannot just downgrade in-place. If you really need to (why?), you may be able to do an export/import.

Comment: If you've opened data files with a newer version of MongoDB (particularly where there is a difference of several major releases), it is likely that incompatible data changes have been persisted. In particular, 1.8 used a different index format. Instead of an in-place downgrade, you could try to `mongodump` from 2.6 and `mongorestore` into 1.8. However, both of these are relatively ancient versions of MongoDB server  - 1.8 was released in March, 2011 and reached end of life in Sept, 2012; 2.6 was released in April, 2014 and reached EOL in Oct, 2016. I'd recommend using a modern server version.